# Cast shadow on 2D grid (1 light source + many walls)

Tags: c++, raster, shadow

In a 30*50 grid, there is 1 light source (**yellow**) and 100+ walls (**red**) scattering around.

### Question

How to calculate report of ***whole screen*** whether each block is in shadow efficiently?  (**grey**=shadow)

Is there a name of such algorithm?

This will be used for AI.  Thus, it must be done in CPU, not GPU.

[image]

### My very slow solution (pseudo code) :-

```
for(auto& block :wholeGrid ){
    bool isInShadow=false;
    for(auto& wall :walls){
        isInShadow ||= check whether "wall" cast shadow on "block" 
    }
    //: get the result of block
}
```

For each pair (block vs wall), it is quite fast.
However, for the whole screen, it is very slow `O(wall*amountOfBlockInWholeScreen)`.

### My second solution :-

Each wall generate 1-3 new fake walls adjacent to itself in an approximate 45-degree direction away from light-source.
It is done from near light source first, then gradually expand.

[image]

It is fast ( `O(amountOfBlockInWholeScreen)`), but it is wrong.
Blue blocks are reported that they are in shadow, but actually they should not.

Comment: Why not replace "45 degree" with the true angle?

Comment: I have had very good results with the recursive shadowcasting algorithm ([1](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=FOV_using_recursive_shadowcasting), [2](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=FOV_using_recursive_shadowcasting_-_improved)).

Comment: What about scanning across each line starting from the bottom -- when you encounter a wall that is not marked as being in shadow, find the two light rays touching either side of the block.  Now visit all cells for scanlines above the wall block lying between these two rays and mark blocks as in shadow.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.  :: Perhaps, I am just dumb.  I can't imagine a way to make those fake walls casting another fake walls correctly without snapping 45 degree.

Comment: @Quentin :: Thank, that looks hopeful and helpful.

Comment: @paddy  :: Oh, it could work!  Hopefully it won't have edge case.  Thank.

Comment: It probably will.  Watch out for light leakage between blocks.  Make sure to use a slightly "greedy" shadow when calculating the boundaries of a ray.  I just pulled that idea out of my butt, so don't waste too much time on it.  Looks like there are much more battle-tested solutions out there.

Comment: @Quentin :: Your linked essay (with ascii diagram) is so easy to understand. Thank.  It even has code for copy paste. You can post it as answer if you wish.